# Using selenium to scrape email addresses with xpath

Tags: python, xml, facebook, selenium, xpath

I want to scrape the email address from the following web page.
[Facebook Business Info Page](https://www.facebook.com/ParisParkerSalonsSpas/info/?tab=page_info)

So I decided to use the selenium driver with Python.  I figured the best way to do this was through defining the xpath.  From inspection of the elements, I noticed that the info I was looking for was found in the following HTML structure as seen here:
[image]

Now I must admit that I am bit of a noob when it comes to using Selenium and defining elements by xpath, so I was hoping someone would correct me if I am defining the following xpath incorrectly.  This is what I have right now:
[image]

But I'm fairly certain I'm defining the wrong xpath.  I know I want to grab the information in the _50f4 div class but I don't know how to define it.  If someone could help me figure that out I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: it is not `input`. it is `div`. Try `//div[@class="_50f4"]`

Comment: Try `//div[@class="_50f4"]`

Comment: Okay, I'll try that.  Thanks!

Comment: unfortunately that didn't appear to work in its entirety.  It would grab some of the emails but not all.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the text of the email address using an xpath like : **//div[@id = 'u_0_u']//ul/li[4]//div[@class = '_50f4']**